# How to show that $\lim_{x\to 0} (1+x)^{1/x}$ is same as $\lim_{x\to +\infty} (1+1/x)^{x}$?

Tags: analysis, limits, real-numbers, infinity

I am trying to calculate $\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{1/x}$ by using that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}(1+1/x)^x=e$.

By substitution with $a=\frac1x$ I get that $\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{1/x}= \lim_{a\to +-\infty}(1+\frac1a)^{a}$. So the Problem is that $x$ approaches $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ (not only $+\infty$).

Is there an easy way to show that $lim(1+a)^{1/a}$ is the same as $a$ approaches $-\infty$ and $+\infty$?

Comment: Check your question title, it is wrong.

Comment: @MarkViola: which one ? The post mentions two distinct limits (that the OP erroneously thinks identical).

Comment: @MarkViola: Hi Mark ! Mh, are you sure ? $1/(1-x)^{1/x}$ and $(1+x)^{1/x}$ aren't so different you know...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. There were some mistakes in the post after an edit. I edited it myself and it should be correct now.

Comment: @yvesdaoust Yes, I was mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to apply the following line of reasoning
$$ \lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/x} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{-x}\right)^{-1/x} = \frac1{\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{-1}{x}\right)^{1/x}} = \frac{1}{e^{-1}} = e. $$

I don't know if there is a better way of approaching this, but I hope this helps!

Comment: You are using the limit that leads to $e^{-1}$, which is not quite immediate from the usual limit to $e$.

Comment: That's true but I think that there is usually not a simple connection between limits to either plus or minus infinity. In this way, it is possible to connect them, although you need indeed that the limit leads to $e^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you, this helps me a lot because I can also use $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{b}{x}\right)^{1/x} =e^{b}$ .

Answer (score 1):

There is confusion in your question and the substitution is wrong.

In fact,

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+x)^{1/x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{1/x}=1$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}(1+x)^{1/x}$$ is not defined as it involves real powers of negative.

There are no connections between

$$\lim_{x\to0}(1+x)^{1/x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+x)^{1/x}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x.$$

Comment: You are right. I was not able to write my equations correctly and someone edited it but messed a bit up. I think it should be correct now... I dont know if I had some mistakes in my original title, but someone that answered before it was edited seems to understand my problem.

Comment: @user84037: Grrrrrrr...